# Swift: Change specific constraint programmatically with animation

Tags: swift, animation, constraints

I have two imageview, and between the two imageViewz I have a small object of 5pt "DragButton".

In my imageview on the left I have a constraint of the right edge that targets the dragbutton.

I want to change this constraint in the code, I want to delete this constraint that binds it to the dragbutton, and replace it with a constraint that binds it to the edge of the right screen, and I want the constraint to be 0 pt like that l image takes the whole width of the screen.

I want to give him an animation here are two screenshots to help you understand:

[image: first picture]

[image: second picture]

Comment: Could you paste the code you have done so far ?

Comment: Do you want it all the way to the right at a specifik moment or all the time? What is it that you want animated?

Comment: I still have not done the code because I do not know how to do it, it will not be all the time like that, just at a precise moment when I execute a function. the normal animation just smooth of 500 millisecond. thanks

Comment: @mickael Should it be able to go back to normal?

Comment: Yes he must be able to return to his position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add both constraints in storyboard (can be created in code also)
1) Image.right <-> ScreenEdge.right (named `pinRight`),
2) Image.right <-> DragButton.left (named `pinRightWithDragButton`).
3) set priority of `pinRight` 999 (less than `pinRightWithDragButton`) (to exist both without warning)
4) create IBOutlet of both, dont make IBOutlet `weak`, remove `weak`
5) enable one and disable the other, at a time in code

```
func makeImageView(fullScreen: Bool) {
    pinRight.isActive = fullScreen
    pinRightWithDragButton.isActive = !fullScreen
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

*Alternatively you can change their priority also.

Answer (score 0):

> Use StackView for this task

I would suggest you add all 3 objects to a horizontal StackView (select all 3, and press the button highlighted in the image provided (don't feel intimidated by my highly professional editing skills :)
[image]

> Add constraints to the StackView, and then play with the StackView options. Also, add only heights and widths to your views and dragButton.

[image]

I would add Spacing -> 5.

Next, add IBOutlets to all 3 objects to your ViewController and, when needed, simply hide objects, and the remaining objects will fill the entire StackView, and then unhide, and the objects will be put back into view and look good. (ex.: obj1.isHidden = true)